# Asp.net multiple replace characters in insert statement?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a SQL insert statement in my asp.net webpage and I have to replace a testbox contents if a ":" exists with nothing"" like the following

```
TextBox.Text.Replace(":", "")
```

Is there a way that I can add an additional character to replace? I need to also remove a "#" if entered into a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if any of these will work, but it's worth a try:

```
TextBox.Text.Replace(":", "").Replace("#", "")
```

Or

```
String mytext = TextBox.Text;
mytext.Replace(":", "");
mytext.Replace("#", "");
TextBox.Text = mytext;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are likely to need to replace more characters, it is worth considering using a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions), like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim t = "Hello: #World!"
        Dim re As New Regex("[#:]")
        Dim u = re.Replace(t, "")
        Console.WriteLine(u)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Outputs:

> Hello World!